# Fix UIView on right bottom of UIWindow

Tags: swift, autolayout

I'm having trouble to pin my floating button on UIWindow. It works properly in usual, but after working with `keyboard`, it's y point gets weird. I mean, sometimes y value gets larger, sometimes y value gets smaller.

[image]
My Approach
1. Using just Frame not works

```
func setFloatyFrame() {
    let xPoint: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width - 56 - 16
    let constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 56 - 49 - 16
    let yPoint = self.view.frame.size.height - constant
    floatyOrigin = CGPoint(x: xPoint, y: yPoint)
    floaty.frame.origin = floatyOrigin
}
```

2. Using AutoLayout also not works

I set my autolayouts like this.

```
func setFloatyConstraints(view: UIView) {
    floaty.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        floaty.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56),
        floaty.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56),
        floaty.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -16),
        floaty.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: constant - 34)
        ])
}
```

Both of these approaches breaks my position of y(only y, x is fine), after I did some keyboard working.

Comment: Provide images, what happening and what you want.

Comment: @PaulMarshal I post new image for this problem.

Comment: I am not sure constraints work absolutely correctly with `UIWindow`. Anyway, I don't see any `bottomAnchor` constraint. Why are you using `topAnchor`?

Comment: `but after working with keyboard,`, What work you have done ? I think there should be some hint related your issue.

Comment: @Sulthan First I did with `bottomAnchor`, but I got some constraints error.

Comment: @PaulMarshal Just appearing my keyboard also makes this problem.

Comment: For your floating button, setting trailing and bottom constraint (+ width and height of course) should be enough. Just make sure bottom constraint is related to the right item. If it is, opening keyboard shouldn't impact the button position. Right now it looks like you set something wrong.